# How to limit the content coming from wordpress shortcodes?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, xml-parsing, jwplayer

I am working on a wordpress shortcodes in which I want to the limit the content coming from a [xml](http://www.cpac.ca/tip-podcast/jwplayer.xml).

The code which I have used in order to create a wordpress shortcode is:

```
function podcast_func( $content = null ){
    ob_start();
    ?>
<script src="https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/FZ8yNTef.js"></script>
<center><div id="podcast" align="center"></div></center> 
<script> 
var PodcastplayerInstance = jwplayer("podcast"); 
PodcastplayerInstance.setup({ 
  playlist: "http://www.cpac.ca/tip-podcast/jwplayer.xml", 
  androidhls: true, 
  preload: "auto", 
  height: 200, 
  width: 400,
  visualplaylist:false,
  stretching: "fill",
    "plugins": {
        "http://www.cpac.ca/tip-podcast/listy.js":{},
        'viral-2': {'oncomplete':'False','onpause':'False','functions':'All'}
    }
});
</script> 
<?PHP
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'podcast', 'podcast_func' );
```

On using this:`<div class="today-podcast" style="text-align: center;">[podcast]</div>`, it displays the entire content from here
http://www.cpac.ca/tip-podcast/jwplayer.xml

**Problem Statement:**
I am wondering what changes I should make in the wordpress shortcode above so that it displays only **1st two items** or **any single item** from here http://www.cpac.ca/tip-podcast/jwplayer.xml

[image]

Comment: Could add an xml parser on your site that gets the remote data and removes all but first 2. Then use endpoint on your server to pass into `setup`

Comment: @charlietfl I am wondering if you can let me know in an answer what I have to do.

Comment: Will require research on your part.....how to get remote xml data using cURL in php , how to parse xml with php etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to 1st save the returned XML to a file and then loop back to unset.

```
<?php
  $curl = curl_init();

  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.cpac.ca/tip-podcast/jwplayer.xml",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "cache-control: no-cache",
      "postman-token: 28025ee8-1e82-ce60-f6ae-f401118baa1c"
    ),
  ));

  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  $err = curl_error($curl);

  curl_close($curl);

  if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
  } else {
    $fp = fopen(ABSPATH.'jwp.xml', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $response);
    fclose($fp);
  }

  $xml = simplexml_load_file(ABSPATH.'jwp.xml');

  for($i = count($xml->channel->item); $i >= 2; $i--){
    unset($xml->channel->item[$i]);
  }

  $xml->saveXML(ABSPATH.'jwp.xml');

  ?>
  <script src="https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/FZ8yNTef.js"></script>
  <center><div id="podcast" align="center"></div></center> 
  <script> 
  var PodcastplayerInstance = jwplayer("podcast"); 
  PodcastplayerInstance.setup({ 
    playlist: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/jwp.xml", 
    androidhls: true, 
    preload: "auto", 
    height: 200, 
    width: 400,
    visualplaylist:false,
    stretching: "fill",
      "plugins": {
          "http://www.cpac.ca/tip-podcast/listy.js":{},
          'viral-2': {'oncomplete':'False','onpause':'False','functions':'All'}
      }
  });
  </script>
```

In case you want the 2nd or 3rd element only, update the above code with the following

```
for($i = count($xml->channel->item); $i >= 3; $i--){
  unset($xml->channel->item[$i]);
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($xml->channel->item); $i++){
  unset($xml->channel->item[0]);
}
```

Comment: I pasted your code [here](http://www.cpac.ca/en/episode/) It says that File not found.

Comment: `copy` function should create a new xml file named `jwp.xml`. Incase the file wasn't created, please use `function_exists` to check `copy` function exists. Another reason could be that the function wasn't able to create the file in the server.

Comment: I pasted this code 
`if (function_exists('copy')) {
    echo "IMAP functions are available.<br />\n";
} else {
    echo "IMAP functions are not available.<br />\n";
}` and it says the following [here](http://www.cpac.ca/en/episode/)

Comment: Its not able to create file on the server I guess.

Comment: in that can we should use `curl` method.

Comment: I am wondering if you can modify the answer. I have never used curl before.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to parse the XML first and generate an array of your desired media objects, rather than accessing the RSS feed directly.

First, you could use [PHPs xpath function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_xpath.asp) to write an xpath query and extract the fields you're looking for. It allows you to select and extract fields from an XML file. Retrieving that XML query might look like this:

```php
    $context  = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept: application/xml')));
    $url = 'http://www.cpac.ca/tip-podcast/jwplayer.xml';

    $xml = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    $itemarray = $xml->xpath("/rss/channel/item[1]");
```

So what are we doing here? We're creating an array containing only the first item in the XML file. That array will look something like this:

```php
    Array
    (
    [0] => Item
         (
         [title] => April 3, 2019
         [description] => Jody Wilson-Raybould...
         [jwplayer:image] => {image URL}
         [jwlplayer:source] => SimpleXMLElement Object
         )
    )
```

At this point, you can parse the array into [media objects](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/customization/configuration-reference/#playlist) to be inserted into your construct as so:

```
$playlist[] = [
     "file" => $itemarray[0][jwplayer:source]->['file'],
     "image" => $itemarray[0][jwplayer:image],
     "description" => $itemarray[0][description],
     "title" => $itemarray[0][title]
     ];
```

Once that's done, you can pass your media object array to the API as normal:

```php
    PodcastplayerInstance.setup({ 
      playlist: <?php echo json_encode($playlist); ?>, 
      androidhls: true,
```

And that should return only the elements you desire. If you want to take it a step further, check out [this shortcode guide](https://pagely.com/blog/the-guide-to-creating-custom-shortcodes-in-wordpress/) to see how you  could set it up to allow the wordpress user to pass the number of objects they'd like to see appear! (I'll leave figuring out how to set up the looping behavior up to you, but I think it's pretty apparent.)

PHP Pros, please forgive my sins, I am very new at this. Corrections to methodology and syntax are welcome and invited in the comments.

Comment: The `playlist: json_encode($playlist)` should be `playlist: <?php echo json_encode($playlist); ?>` ..

Comment: This actually brings up an interesting question to me! I don't think he wants it to be echoed, because he's writing a shortcode (wordpress requires that you return output for shortcodes, not echo). But now that you point it out, that code actually won't work because of the ?> after the ob_start function. How could he include it in the return of his function? Would echo do that in this case?

Comment: He is using output buffering, so echoing there isn't an issue. Have you tried his code? And he's returning the output using `ob_get_clean()`.

Comment: I haven't run it yet, no. I haven't messed around with output buffering yet (I'm new! :D).

Comment: @flash Hey, I don't think I can really offer one-on-one coaching. If you have a question, I can try to answer here in the comments, but I'd treat my suggestion more like pseudo code. It really isn't a fully fleshed out script.